# Automatic Type Conversion / Null Handling with VB.NET and MySQL Database

Tags: vb.net, vb6, ado, adodb, vb6-migration

Working on converting some projects from VB6 to VB.NET 2012 (same issue occured in VB.NET 2002, 2005, 2008, and 2012)

The problem I find most annoying is that with a typical ADO connection in VB6, I could pull my data, and any field that may be a string, I could add & "", to ensure it returns no nulls, yet maintain using null on the server for optimal database integrity.

When attempting something so simple in .NET, the procedure is many times more complex, and I find that each individual field must now be converted before you can even use the data - in addition, to forced null checking in various ways depending on the field data type -- which you must know before-hand in order to play.

What is the equivalent of the following VB6 code in VB.NET  ?

```
    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    sSQL = "SELECT reminderdate FROM notes WHERE uniqueid=" & NoteID
    cn.Open "Provider=MSDASQL.1;Persist Security Info=False;Extended Properties=" & Chr(34) & "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};SERVER=" & DatabaseServer & ";DATABASE=" & DatabaseName & ";UID=" & DatabaseUsername & ";PWD=" & DatabasePassword & ";OPTION=16427" & Chr(34) & ";Initial Catalog=" & DatabaseName & ""
    rs.Open sSQL, cn, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly
    If rs.EOF = False Then
        While rs.EOF = False
            For Each rs.Fields as fieldData
                 Debug.Print fieldData & "|"
            Next fieldData
            Debug.Print "===========" ' Delimited for next record data
        Wend
    End If
    rs.Close
    cn.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set cn = Nothing
```

Please understand that the above code does not care what the type of the data is, doesn't care how many fields are in the database, nor does it care how many records exist.

---

EDIT: I assumed that since I stated I wish to do the equivalent in .NET, that it was clear that I wished to use .NET components, not COM for the connections.

Please see the documentation here on how to use the MySqlData connector which is a native .NET component.

[MySqlConnection Examples](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqlconnection.html)

Comment: Alright, knock it off, both of you. This discussion is going nowhere productive, so I'm wiping it. I suggest you both walk away and leave this alone.

Comment: It seems that you should focus your question more towards how to set a VB.NET database connection. For that you should specify the DB you want and the problems you found (the link you are including contains perfectly working codes; what is your doubt?). This is all my help, take it or leave it; but lets better stop all the communication here, don't you think?